# Algorithm to quickly determine sets that include an element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a large number of sets, each of which includes an unspecified number of elements. Is there an algorithm to quickly determine which sets include an element of interest?
For example, let's say there are 10,000,000 sets and I want to know exactly which sets include element A?

A simple method is to iterate through all the sets and check if element A is present, however, as the sets and elements grow large, this brute-force method proves very time-consuming.

Comment: Create a map of element and set ID?

Comment: You could reverse the data structure: consider each element as the set of all sets that contain this element

Comment: @Khanh Great, so can you answer your own question or close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the stack overflow community and especially @nice_dev and @stef, we can quickly identify the set by building a map with keys the element IDs and values the set IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Extra Map<Key, value> data structure that stores the keys (you data) and value as (you set) .